# find the latest file in folder linux

Tags: python, linux

I have created multiple file in directory. How to find latest in the folder? I have created a python code for this:

```
for f in os.listdir(root_location):
  command = "find {}{}  -type f -mmin -10".format(root_location, f)
  p = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, shell=True)
  out, err = p.communicate()
  print(out.decode("utf-8"))
```

Here root_location is /app/data/programs/. Inside programs folder there are more than 200 folders and in those 200 folders there could be atleast 20 subfolders. Now file can be created in any one of this 20 subfolders.

This python code is executed in crontab after every 30 sec. But still it is slow. Because if file is created in 200th folder then it will show new file data very late.

How to optimize this?

Comment: You don't need 200 `find` commands.  You can do it with a single `find`.  In that case, though, why use Python?  Why not just put the `find` in your crontab?

Comment: To be clear... You want a list of all files modified in the last 10 minutes. Is that right?

Comment: Yes right. Thing is after getting that list I am adding those file in database. And also find command on /app/data/programs/ directory takes almost 2 min to execute and if I execute find in each directory from /app/data/programs/ it takes ~500ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pure Python approach that uses multithreading to potentially help with performance. Each directory is parsed in its own thread:

```
from threading import Thread
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime

START = datetime.now()
AGE = 600 # seconds

def process(_dir=Path('/Volumes/G-Drive')):
    for e in _dir.glob('*'):
        if e.is_dir():
            Thread(target=process, args=(e,)).start()
        else:
            mtime = datetime.fromtimestamp(e.stat().st_mtime)
            if (START - mtime).total_seconds() <= AGE:
                print(e) # process the file here


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target=process).start()
```

**Performance:**

This was tested on a filesystem with 11,868 directories containing 133,696 plain files. The total runtime was ~9.5 seconds

Comment: This works. For me it tooks ~15seconds to complete. But how can we scedule it in crontab. From crontab it is not working. But if we run it as script it works

Comment: Probably the simplest way would be to write a shell script that runs the Python code after setting up relevant environment variables. The execution the shell script from cron